# Setting locale error with i18n in converse.js

Tags: javascript, locale, converse.js

i have built the converse.js files according to the steps in option 3 in this link: https://conversejs.org/docs/html/quickstart.html
Then i had the JavaScript and CSS files in Dist directory. I saved the dist directory in my webpage root directory.
Then i added the JavaScript and CSS filed to the head section of the index page. I also initialized the converse.js in the bottom section of the index page. Everything worked perfect with this integration.

I also changed the locale to different languages which can be found in '/dist/locale' directory. I am able to change the
locale to all the 39 languages except one: 'ug'. This is a new language which i have translated recently.

When i set i18n to 'ug', the converse.js is in English which is failure in the setting. Then i looked at
the browser console to see if there is any errors. I found the following errors for the issue:

```
 FATAL: Cannot find module './ug.js' log.js:68:19
    log log.js:68
    fatal log.js:93
    initialize index.js:121
    initialize core.js:574
    initialize converse.js:53
    initialize entry.js:31
    <anonymous> index.html:57
```

can anybody knows how to solve the issue? Thanks

I expect to see the converse.js in Uyghur lanugage.

Comment: Can you post your code? It might be a case of improper localization, but until we see your code, we can only offer guesses. Also, what happens if you set the locale to French, Dutch, or German?

Comment: <script>
    converse.initialize({
        bosh_service_url: 'https://conversejs.org/http-bind/', // Please use this connection manager only for testing purposes
        show_controlbox_by_default: true,
  i18n:'tr',
    });
  </script>

I used above code to initialize converse.js to Turkish language. It works fine. It also works fine with English, Arabic, French, Italian etc. But when i set to 'ug', i had the error shown in the post.